# STL vector deallocation

Tags: c++, stl, vector

Given an STL `vector` of pointers, each element has to be deallocated before destroying the `vector` itself. Is there any technical implication that prevents the STL library for doing it automatically?

Thanks

Comment: "given an STL vector of pointers, each element has to be deallocated before destroying the vector itself" No, that doesn't follow. In any case, manually managing resources is bad. Use a smart pointer.

Answer (score 5):

The reason the STL doesn't do it for you is that it can't know whether or not it's supposed to.  You might have a vector of pointers to arrays (in which case it needs to do `delete[]`), of pointers to regular objects (in which case it would need to do `delete`), or possibly memory from some custom allocator.  Those pointers could also be shared with some other objects, in which case deleting them would cause those other objects to point at garbage data, leading to undefined behavior.  Those pointers could also be to stack-allocated memory, in which case no deallocation is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

you can store there pointers that shouldn't be deleted when vector is destructed

use vector of smart pointer (e.g. boost::shared_ptr) to receive automatic deallocation

Answer (score 2):

If a vector contains pointers, it does not mean that the pointers point to dynamic memory. And if they do, should `delete` or `delete[]` be applied to each pointer? And what if the pointers points to objects created using placement new? All these question should be answered by the programmer, not by the library.

Comment: "does not mean...point to static memory" should say "dynamic".

Comment: @Tony Yep, one of the weirdest typos I ever made :-) Thanks for pointing that out.